# Extracting Windows 8 Start Screen Patterns

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

Is there any way to extract the Windows 8 Start Screen patterns, in order to use them as standalone wallpapers on other systems?

For example see this screenshot:

[image: Windows 8 RTM Start Screen]

I am interested in the dark blue background. I heard that this background is somehow adapted to your chosen color theme. So many different variations should exist.

Engadget has an article [here](http://www.engadget.com/2012/08/15/windows-8-rtm-whats-new/) briefly talking about these background patterns and the different color schemes. They call them "personalization tattoos".

[image: Changing Windows 8 Start Screen Color Scheme and Pattern]

**Update:**

I found the following page/guide:
http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-or-change-start-screen-green-background-start-button-tiny-start-menu-and-other-metro-ui-stuff-in-windows-8/

This looks a very good way to achieve my goal. Unfortunately the guide seems to be dated.

I tried to find `shsxs.dll` on the RTM of Windows 8 without much luck. It looks like Microsoft changed the way they handle the background image. The file is nowhere to be found...

I also looked into `uxtheme.dll`, but it doesn't contain any interesting images.

Any new ideas? Any other *.dll with might be of interest here?

Comment: Do you mean the default wallpapers location ?

Comment: As in: 1) Take a picture of the win8 screen. 2) Use that picture as a background on win7 to fake a win8 install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution!

All the required information can be found on this page:

http://code-bude.net/2012/08/31/anleitung-benutzerdefinierte-hintergrundbilder-in-windows-8/(German)

Basically the new file containing the images is `imageres.dll`. Opening it with ResourceHacker reveals all the wallpapers in the PNG section.

The backgrounds begin with Resource 10000. For each pattern(and some colors?) there are 5 images each.

- 10000 - Small preview in settings
- 10001 - Background for low resolution devices
- 10002 - Background for mid resolution devices
- 10003 - Background for high resolution devices
- 10004 - Large preview in settings

For example exporting 10003 creates a 3000x800px PNG:

[image: 10003.png]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to extract the Windows 8 Start Screen patterns, in order to use them as standalone wallpapers on other systems?

## Yes, there is.

The backgrounds reside in `%systemroot%/system32/imageres.dll`. To use them, I suggest the following method:

Start by opening the folder where our resource-file is, by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and entering `%systemroot%/system32`.

Extract the resources by using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), *(right-click)* on `imageres.dll` and select `7-Zip > Open archive`.
Dwelve into the archive by opening `.rsrc/png`. This is where you'll find the backgrounds. To extract, select the files you want and *(left-click)* the Extract button and select where the selected files should end up, e.g. `C:\Windows 8 Start Screen Backgrounds` *Note: Backward-slashes are important!*

The resources extracted don't have a file extension, we need to add that by renaming our files. Navigate to the folder where you extracted the resources, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and *(right-click)* in the folder, *(left-click)* on **Open command window here**.

Inside the Command Prompt, type and execute the following command: `REN * *.png`

#### Congratulations! Now you have all the resources at your disposal.

**Note:** Windows 8.1 removes the old start screen backgrounds 10000-11904, if you want those you'll have to get hold of an imageres.dll file from a Windows 8.0 installation. The new Windows 8.1 backgrounds follow the same principle for extraction, but have the numbers 20001-22101 instead.

Comment: Can you give me a ZIP file for these

Answer (score 0):

For every single start screen background you can choose different colors and different sizes to fit your screen resolution, so I believe those images are generated and not stored individually on the disk.

A good way to get them is by `print screen`. Use Microsoft's zoom out feature to make the tiles occupy less space, make the print screen and remove unnecessary stuff using a photo editor.

Or, search them on Google. This is how I found this [one](http://bsodman.deviantart.com/#/d4ue58e).

Comment: That is what I though too, but fortunately this is not the case. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows 8 Start Screen Customizer by Vhanla.

Download link can be found [here](http://vhanla.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-Start-Screen-Customizer-v1-3-beta-337308916)